# How to use jQuery to handle dynamically added script tags in parallel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Here is my situation: I dynamically added 2 scripts through

```
$('body').append('<script src="http://localhost:8080/script_1.js"></script>');
$('body').append('<script src="http://localhost:8080/script_2.js"></script>');
```

Then I found they would be loaded in sequence instead of parallel from chrome console.

However, they could be loaded in parallel if I use either native js

```
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

or jQuery function: getScript

```
$.getScript('http://localhost:8080/script_1.js');
```

I searched a lot and found that jQuery actually will remove the script tag, parse the source, and use its ajax function $.ajax() to load script instead of letting browser to handle. But $.getScript() function also uses $.ajax() and have no blocking. Obviously, it's not the fault of $.ajax().

Here is a test case:
Go to http://jquery.com and paste following script in the console which will add a js file twice through jQuery

```
$('body').append('<script src="/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/js/plugins.js"></script>');
$('body').append('<script src="/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/js/plugins.js"></script>');
```

Check the timeline, you'll find they are loaded in sequence.
Of course, I can use native js or $.getScript() above to save my time.

However, I want to know why? Why are these jQuery ajax call from adding script tag not in parallel?

**Update**

More interesting, seems the sequence only apply to the script from **the same origin**.
I tried to load some js files form google hosted libraries and they are in parallel. Tried following also in http://jquery.com

```
$('body').append('<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/ext-core/3.1.0/ext-core.js"></script>');
$('body').append('<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/ext-core/3.1.0/ext-core.js"></script>');
```

Comment: "Scripts that are dynamically created and added to the document are async by default" according to [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/) but it doesn't explain why this isn't the case for jQuery appended local scripts.

Comment: @Moob yeah, I know...as I mentioned, I can use pure javascript `document.body.appendChild(script);` to load and yes, they're parallel...but i just want to find out what is done secretly to make my case become sequential

Comment: There are some clues in the spec https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#script but - in their words: "The exact processing details for these attributes are, for mostly historical reasons, somewhat non-trivial, involving a number of aspects of HTML. The implementation requirements are therefore by necessity scattered throughout the specification..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When appending scripts to the DOM, depending on the cross-domain test, different ajaxTransport functions are used.

> A cross-domain request happens when we have a protocol:host:port
>   mismatch

In the first case **same-origin**:

JQuery uses the [XMLHttpRequest open](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-xmlhttprequest-open) function with `async=false` forcing a synchrounous request ([see source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/xhr.js#L49)).

```
xhr.open(
        options.type,
        options.url,
        options.async,
        options.username,
        options.password
    );
```

Hence the warning on the console (at least on Canary anyway).

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated

In the second case **cross-origin**:

JQuery uses ajax as follows([see source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/script.js#L55))

```
script = jQuery("<script>").prop({
                    async: true,
                    charset: s.scriptCharset,
                    src: s.url
                }).....
document.head.appendChild(script[0]);
```

which will load in parallel as you have stated.